# How to work with the Entity Registration module in Drupal 7?

Tags: module, drupal-7, field, content-type

I am working on [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module in my Drupal 7 site. I have created the entity-type and have also added fields, but now I am stuck at the point where I have to create the registrants and display the registration form on my site.

Any suggestions to get me going?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the community documentation of [Entity Registrations](https://drupal.org/node/1463042) module:

- Create at least one registration bundle (or type) at
  admin/structure/registration/registration_types, much like you would a content type.
- Add a registration field to any entity you want to enable registrations
  for. Note the display options: default, link to the registration form,
  and embedding the actual form.
- When you add or edit an entity, select the registration bundle you want to
  use for.
- Registrations are now enabled for the entity and you can configure the
  registration settings via a local task.

Comment: Thank You nk-47, I got it, now the emails are not being delivered on registrations. How to enable the email delivery.

Answer (score 1):

Some details about the [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) (from its project page), that ***may*** help to get you going with this great module:

> A quick outline of how it works:
>
> - You create a registration type, and add Drupal fields (like shoe size or meal preference) to it for information you want to gather from registrants
> - On some entity that you want to allow registrations for (maybe an "event" content type), add a custom field of type "Registration"
> - Create an instance of that entity, and select one of the registration types you created in the Registration field.
> - Start taking registrations when viewing your entity!
>
> There are additional settings, but that is the basic outline: just create a registration type or two, give your entity a registration field, and point it at one of your registration types.

For more detailed instructions, do NOT refer to the README (as suggested on its project page) since that link doesn't work ... Instead use the [Read documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1463042) link (also on the project page), which is the community documentation about this module.

Also have a look at the video about [Drupal 7 Entity Registration Module](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVH-9A0jxWM) for a great introduction to it.

**PS**: This module is all about entities. So it should also work together with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module pretty well.